# Why is 'IS NULL' 100x slower than 'length() = 0' on a blob column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am having a ~90 MB database consisting mostly on message attachments including a BLOB column `content`, that stores the binary attachment data.

I assume it is not wise to create an index over a BLOBs, so no indexes involved apart from the autoindex.

For getting empty attachments, I compared the following querys:

```
SELECT message_id FROM attachments WHERE content IS NULL;
```

and

```
SELECT message_id FROM attachments WHERE length(content) = 0;
```

which result in the same rows in my usecase.

Why does the first one take 250ms and the second one only 1-2ms (both on a SSD)? What is the reason behind that? Is there a hidden length index or something? Any insight appreciated.

**Additional info**

1. The `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` in both cases is

   0|0|0|SCAN TABLE attachments
2. The negation `IS NOT NULL` vs. `length() != 0` results in the same performance difference 250ms vs. 2ms.
3. In combined querys that do only include {NULL} columns `WHERE content IS NULL AND length(content) = 0;` takes 250ms and `WHERE length(content) = 0 AND content IS NULL;` takes 2ms.

Comment: Are you sure your comparison is correct? Was the data just cached? What happens if, after starting up a fresh instance of the sqlite client, you execute the second query first? Or repeat each query a few times, taking the fastest run as a reference?

Comment: I can reproduce the fast and the slow query unlimited times in any order in one or more sqlite3 processes. What do you mean with "comparison is correct"?

Comment: I would assume this is because the column length is stored, so the length check doesn't require the contents of the BLOB to be retrieved.  You still have to scan each record, but there is at least one additional read per record for the NULL check.  Of course, IS NULL could / should be optimised to use the record length.  Take a look at https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html, especially the section "2.1 Record Format".

Comment: Good point, looks like a missing optimization to me. See (3.) in my question. I think it is safe to add length() = 0 before every `IS NULL` query.

Comment: I would be somewhat surprised if IS NULL could be optimized to use the record length, there's a difference between a column having data which is of 0 length and a column being NULL. Also length(NULL) is NULL, length(content) = 0 is NULL for NULL entries.

Comment: Jap, I was wrong assuming `length(NULL) = 0`

Comment: With SQLite 3.8.0 or later, you could create a [partial index](http://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html) for only those rows where the content is NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are simply different queries: `LENGTH` is a scalar function which returns (see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html))

(i) `NULL` if the input is `NULL`
(ii) `0` if the input is a string of zero length (or if it is convertible to a string, resp.).

Therefore the condition `length(content)=0` is true for content being an empty string, and false when content is `NULL` (because comparison with `NULL` always is false).

Based on this, I guess that your table contains several `NULL` fields and only a few which actually contain a value. This is supported also by your second additional info, where you say that `IS NOT NULL` shows a comparable performance.

Comment: I wanted to point the same thing IS NULL <> len(content) = 0. If field is '' len(content) = 0 but but if field is null len(content) = null

Comment: Based on your answer, I found that `length(content) IS NULL` results in the same rows as `content IS NULL` since `length(X) = NULL` if and only if `X = NULL`, but is even faster (500x in my case and 20x for the nonempty-case). If you could verify and add that to the answer, I'd love to accept it.

Comment: @Simon Warta: I don't have an explanation for that and I'm also not able to verify it at the moment. However, if `length(content) IS NULL` performs faster than `content IS NULL`, this would be the real interesting point here (since from the first I would expect `length()` to take at least one more operation).

Comment: Since you answered my original question perfectly correct, I opened a follow-up question, that is free of my noise of being unable to read the manual: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801658/is-length-is-null-equivalent-and-faster-than-is-null-for-blobs