# Is 'length() IS NULL' equivalent and faster than 'IS NULL' for BLOBs?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am having a ~90 MB SQLite database on a SSD consisting mostly on message attachments including a BLOB column content, that stores the binary attachment data.

Now I found that the following query

```
SELECT message_id FROM attachments WHERE length(content) IS NULL;
```

is 500x faster (0.5ms vs. 250ms) than the original

```
SELECT message_id FROM attachments WHERE content IS NULL;
```

Is it true, that both queries are equivalent?

**Additional info**

1. No indexes are involved apart from the autoindex.
2. It's not caching. The result can be reproducued unlimited times in any order from any number of SQLite processes.

Comment: `length(NULL)` is not 0 but NULL, thus the previous question was not a performance issue but I was not able to read the manual correctly.

Comment: Record length is presumably part of the metadata for each record so perhaps a zero-length check bypasses the physical table entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQLite, the length and type of each column value are stored [at the beginning of the row](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format).
This allows the `length()` and `typeof()` functions to be optimized to avoid loading the actual value.

The IS NULL operator has no such optimization (although it would be possible to implement it).

Answer (score 3):

I made a script to benchmark both functions. `length(x) IS NULL` is faster unless you have mostly `NULL` values.

### Results:

- 50% alternating between random data and null:

  - `IS NULL`: 11.343180236999842
  - `length(x) IS NULL`: 7.824154090999855
- Entirely blobs, no nulls:

  - `IS NULL`: 15.019244787999924
  - `length(x) IS NULL`: 7.527420233999919
- Entirely nulls, no blobs:

  - `IS NULL`: 6.184766045999822
  - `length(x) IS NULL`: 6.448342310000044

### Test script:

```python
import sqlite3
import timeit

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test")
c.execute("CREATE TABLE test (data BLOB)")

for i in range(10000):
    # Modify this to change data
    if i % 2 == 0:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES (randomblob(1024))")
    else:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES (NULL)")

def timeit_isnull():
    c.execute("SELECT data IS NULL AS dataisnull FROM test")
    c.fetchall()

def timeit_lenisnull():
    c.execute("SELECT length(data) IS NULL AS dataisnull FROM test")
    c.fetchall()

print(timeit.timeit(timeit_isnull, number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(timeit_lenisnull, number=1000))
```

Comment: Great work, thx. I compared different per cell blob sizes and it turned out, that the performance gain in a 50/50 mix of data/NULL depends very much on the size of blob https://gist.github.com/webmaster128/e580fe249f95f60b6b0a

Answer (score 1):

Actually using `LENGTH(some_blob_content)` instructs MySQL server 5.5 and above to bypass row-scanning, this is the reason for improved performance of your query, because the data is read directly from meta-data table.

EDIT:

In SQLite during part `INSERT` and `SELECT` processing, the complete content of each row in the database **is encoded as a single BLOB**. See [here](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) for details.

> Also for a string value X, the `length(X)` function returns the number
>   of characters (**not bytes**) in X prior to the first `NULL`
>   character. Since SQLite strings do not normally contain `NULL`
>   characters, the `length(X)` function will **usually** return the total
>   number of characters in the string X. For a `blob` value X,
>   `length(X)` returns the **number of bytes** in the blob. If X is
>   `NULL` then `length(X)` is NULL. If X is numeric then `length(X)`
>   returns the length of a string representation of X.

The above quote from the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length) suggests that, **for blob values**, the procedure of reading their length is the same as in MySQL, i.e. from meta-data table.

Comment: I don't know how MySQL and SQLite differ in this implementation. Couldn't use MySQL the meta-data for `WHERE content IS NULL` too? Or does it actually do that?